# Bash scripting missing ']'

Tags: bash, scripting

I am getting an error ./test.sh: line 13: [: missing `]' in the file test.sh
I tried using brackets and other options such as -a or by checking the size of the file p1 but the error is always there and the else statement is always executed irrespective of the input given.I even tried by removing the ; in line 13 but it didn't help.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter app name"
read y
$y &
top -b -n 1 > topLog.log
#-w checks for the whole word not and sub string from that word
grep -w "$y" topLog.log > p1
#-s option checks if the file p1 is present or not
if [ -s "p1"];  #line 13
then 
    echo "Successful "
else
    echo "Unsuccessful"
fi
rm p1
```

I am new to bash scripting.So if there is any silly mistake please excuse me.

Comment: "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." never mind the hundreds of people who have upvoted the answers below...

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Change

```
if [ -s "p1"];  #line 13
```

into

```
if [ -s "p1" ];  #line 13
```

note the space.

Comment: I literally just spent about 8 hours before I found my same mistake...after reading this :)

Comment: i spent 8 minutes to fix this.... i am like wtf

Answer (score 70):

I got this error while trying to use the `&&` operator inside single brackets like `[ ... && ... ]`.  I had to switch to `[[ ... && ... ]]`.

Comment: I was also using && with if and it solved my problem.

Comment: I was using == operator and had the same issue, switching to double square bracket helped, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You're missing a space after `"p1"`:

```
if [ -s "p1" ];
```

Comment: This has saved me some time wondering and searching for the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

add a space before the close bracket

Answer (score -1):

If you created your script on windows and want to run it on linux machine, and you're sure there is no mistake in your code, install **dos2unix** on linux machine and run `dos2unix yourscript.sh`. Then, run the script.