# shell scripting error [: missing `]' on if condition

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute the following if condition

```
if [ [ -z "$TC_ID_114" -o "$TC_ID_114" == "yes" || "$PTYPE" == "PROD_LTE_WMP" || "$PTYPE" == "PROD_WCDMA" ] ] && [ "$UTYPE" == "UNIT_FZM" ]; then
    TC_ID_114_STR="Configuring NTP Server IP"
    TC_ID_114_VAR1="2001::2"
    log_tc_start "TC_ID_114" "$TC_ID_114_STR"
    $OBJCLI ip_testsuite $FEATURE $SET_NTP_RULES "$TC_ID_114_VAR1"
    if ! validate_CreateNTP $TC_ID_114_VAR1 "ipv6" ; then
        TC_CUR_RESULT="$SUCC"
    fi
    cat "$IPTS_LOG" ; > "$IPTS_LOG"
    delNTP $TC_ID_114_VAR1
    log_tc_result
    log_tc_end
fi
```

and getting error as `` [: missing `]' ``

Comment: Please add an [mcve]

Comment: Remove spaces between [[ and ]]

Comment: there is a space between [ [ and ] ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash scripting missing '\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993062/bash-scripting-missing)

Comment: i checked the same before, but i dont have any spacing issue in my code

Comment: You do have a spacing problem, whether you think you do or not.  The first `[` (test) command is given arguments `[ -z "$TC_ID_114" -o "$TC_ID_114" == "yes"` then the regular shell `||` operator appears.  There's no `]` for it.  The `[` command is not special case syntax; it is just a fussy command that expects its last argument to be `]` (and won't accept `[` as its first argument, but that problem comes later).  You should probably be writing `[[ -z "$TC_ID_114" || "$TC_ID_114" == "yes" || … ]]` — you should not be mixing `-o` with `||` (consistency, if nothing else).

Comment: Note that the square brackets are not simply grouping operators, either.

Comment: i want [ -z "$TC_ID_114" -o "$TC_ID_114" == "yes" || "$PTYPE" == "PROD_LTE_WMP" || "$PTYPE" == "PROD_WCDMA" ] to be as one group and [ "$UTYPE" == "UNIT_FZM" ] condition... in that case how do i do so? i am new to shell script, please suggest