# [: missing `]' error in Unix | shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I got a [: missing `]'   error in shell Script

```
memuse=$ free -m                                                                      
if [ $memuse >80]
then                                                               
echo "Attention: memory utilisation is high on $(hostname) at $(date)"
```

This is my code and i got the error like

```
[tono@webminal.org ~]$sh ./memory_alert.sh                                   
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available       
Mem:          14522        2128        4004        1845        8389       10096       
Swap:             0           0           0                                           
./memory_alert.sh: line 2: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: Use this link to debug: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: A problem that others haven't mentioned is that you don't use `>` for numeric comparisons in `[ ... ]`. If `$memuse` contained an integer value (which it definitely doesn't), the comparison would be `if [ "$memuse" -gt 80 ]`

Comment: There are many problems with your code, but the most crucial one which throws the error is the missing space before `]`. Although fixing 5hat will still not make your code run. See the comment of @user123

Comment: @TonoKuriakose : Just for additional information (as others have already pointed out the errors in your program): Your `if` statement actually means to run the command `test $memuse >80]`, i.e. uses the expanded value of `$memuse` as argument to `test` and then writes the stdout of `test` to a file named `80]`. I guess you will find an empty file of this name in the working directory of your script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash scripting missing '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993062/bash-scripting-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

```
memuse=$ free -m                                                                      
if [ $memuse > 80 ];                                                                  
then                                                                                 
echo "Attention: memory utilisation is high on $(hostname) at $(date)"               
else                                                                                  
echo "Attention : memory utilisation is normal on $(hostname) at $(date)"             
fi
```

This is my first time doing bash scripting. So the issue majorly  due to the Indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a lot of problems. First, to get output of some command to a var you need this

```
var=$( some_command )
```

Second, the output of `free -m` is

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available       
Mem:          14522        2128        4004        1845        8389       10096       
Swap:             0           0           0
```

How can it be compared with just 80? Look what you are trying to compare:

```
"total used free shared buff/cache availableMem: 14522 2128 4004 1845 8389 10096 Swap: 0 0 0" > 80
```

Third, `free -m` is showing mem info in megabytes and I assume you want percentage, right?
There is no such metric in `free` output. But based on 'available' and 'total' you can calculate mem usage in % and than compare it to some predefined value. Ok lets try to fix that.

```
#!/bin/bash

memory_alert=80 # this will be an alerting value
memory_total=$( free | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $2}' ) # get total memory by parsing free output with sed and awk
memory_available=$( free | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $7}' ) # same with available memory
memory_used=$( echo 100-100*$memory_available/$memory_total | bc ) # calculate memory usage in %

# compare and alert if memory usage more than 80%
(( memory_used > memory_alert )) && echo "Attention: memory utilisation is high on $(hostname) at $(date)"
```

And more compact variant thanks to Gordon

```
#!/bin/bash
memory_alert=80 # this will be an alerting value
memory_used=$( free | awk 'NR==2 {print int(100-100*$7/$2)}' )
(( memory_used > memory_alert )) && echo "Attention: memory utilisation is high on $(hostname) at $(date)"
```

Comment: @KeithThompson, Thank you!)

Comment: You can have `awk` do almost all of the work for you: `memory_used=$( free | awk 'NR==2 {print int(100-100*$7/$2)}' )`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an issue in this line `memuse=$ free -m`

What I'm understanding you wanted to assign the output of `free -m` command to variable "memuse" but that is incorrect. Instead use `$(command)` or `` `command` `` syntax.
Also add an echo statement for variable `memuse` just to check what are you getting as a response of command `free -m` in variable `memuse`. That will be helpful for you.

```
memuse=$(free -m)
echo $memuse
```

**`Output`**

```
$bash -f main.sh
total used free shared buff/cache available Mem: 257692 3748 244035 3 9909 252827 Swap: 4095 0 4095
```

Comment: you should add corrected code to your answer for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is syntax error in `memuse=$ free -m`, it should be like this:

```
memuse=$(free -mh)
```

Secondly, in `if [ $memuse > 80 ]`, you have not mentioned either it is a percentage or the absolute used memory value, if it's a percentage you are checking then you will need to calculate it accordingly using the percentage formula.

If it is an absolute value, then you will have to use grep etc to get the used memory value and compare it with 80.

Answer (score -2):

you missed `space` and `fi`

```
memuse=$ free -m                                                                      
if [ $memuse > 80 ];
then                                                               
    echo "Attention: memory utilisation is high on $(hostname) at $(date)"
fi
```

Comment: Have you tested your posted code?

Comment: yeah, I tested it locally

Comment: I would recommend to [check your code here](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Thanks, Your answer gave me the solution